# How to relayout a dialog in swt after the visibility of group inside it is set to false

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, swt, jface

I have created a dialog in swt inside which there is a group which gets visible only when a checkbox in a dialog is checked.How can i do this kind of relayouting on setting the visibility of group to false and vice versa.Pls suggest.

Comment: add group of components to a panel, use setVisible over the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `SelectionAdapter` to the checkbox button and in the `widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)` method you should make your group visible (probably you'd want to put it on a `Composite` and make the Composite visible so you can add more components if you want) and call `layout()`

```
checkbox.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        yourComposite.setVisible(checkbox.getSelection());
        yourComposite.layout();
    }
});
```